# SASS cant including Gulp

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, gulp, compass

I have a problem with including compass. This is error that i get:

> "Error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass.\A Load path:
>   /usr/local/www/project/sass\A on line 1 of sass/style.scss\A \A 1:
>   @import 'compass';\A 2: @import 'compass/reset';\A 3: @import
>   \"compass/layout/sticky-footer\";\A 4: @import 'susy';\A 5: @import
>   'breakpoint';\A 6: "

Here it's code that is in gulp:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var compass = require('gulp-compass');
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');



gulp.task('compass', function() {
  gulp.src('sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(compass({
      config_file: 'config.rb',
      css: 'css',
      sass: 'sass'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});


gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return sass('sass', { sourcemap: true })
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.error('Error', err.message);
   })

    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())

    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});


gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'compass']);
```

Any advice, solutions....

Comment: have you installed the ruby gem? `gem install compass`

Comment: yes, the compass is installed

Comment: Hard to tell without more of the code. In the error message it says: "File to import not found .... on line 1 of sass/style.scss". What @import 's do you have in this sass file? Try disabling them, do you get the same error?

Comment: This is what i have in style.scss
import 'compass';
import "compass/layout/sticky-footer";
import 'susy';
import 'breakpoint';

$susy: (
  container: 1000px,
  columns: 24,
  gutters: 1/6
);

Comment: Are you sure the sass compass import is pointing to the right directories? If you remove the compass imports, it sounds like it should work, which means it's not pointing to the right directory. It seems like this issue is to do with the sass imports rather than gulp configuration.

Comment: Message when gulp is runnes through putty

`Using gulpfile ~project/gulpfile.js
Starting 'sass'..
Starting 'compass'..
Finished 'compass' after 6.39 ms
gulp-ruby-sass stdout: directory
gulp-ruby-sass stdout: write ie.css
gulp-ruby-sass stdout: write ie.css.map
gulp-ruby-sass stdout: write print.css
gulp-ruby-sass stdout: write print.css.map
Error error sass/screen.scss (Line 6: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/reset.
Load path: /usr/local/www/project/sass)
Error error sass/style.scss (Line 3: File to import not found or unreadable: susy.
Load path: /usr/local/www/project/sass)`